# GCM - Generating different registration IDs when compiled in different computers

Tags: android

I would like to ask something about GCM and I found that there is not much resource in the Internet talking the problem below.

I integrated GCM into my own app. The registration IDs of all users will be stored in my notification server. All working fine. But here comes the problem:

I compiled the source files at computer A and generated an APK file and installed that APK on my own device (S3). It does receive messages from GCM. But when I compiled the source at another computer B and generated the same APK and installed on the same device (S3), the registration ID changed!

This does not make sense! One user would get two identical messages as their registration IDs were stored in the notification server.

So, what I want to ask is that is there any solution that could solve this? What are the rules or condition for Google to generate/change registration IDs?

I've been racking my brain to get this stuff worked. But still failed...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the response you get back from Google when you send a message to those two different regids, then **one** of the responses will contain a canonical id. This indicates that the regid should no longer be used as it has been superseded by the one that did not elicit a canonical id.